# how to use django pagination?

Tags: nonetype, django-pagination

i have a django project  and it includes pagination i do not know where is the error in my code but once i tired to go to the next or previous page it crash and display the below error :

> can only concatenate str(not ""NoneType) to str

```
        query=request.GET.get("search")
        paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 5) 
        page_request_var = "page"
        print("page_request_var===>",page_request_var)
        page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
        print("page===>",page)
        queryset = paginator.get_page(page)
        print("queryset===>",queryset)
```

When i print **page** it display None

In the browser it suppose to display **page=2&search=sam**
but instead 
it display **/?=2&20search%20=%20sam**

Answer (score -2):

I suggest doing something like the below two links. The first link is best practices for large datasets.

1.[how-organize-pagination-with-a-large-number-of-pages-in-django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63506609/how-organize-pagination-with-a-large-number-of-pages-in-django-project/63507365#63507365)

2.[pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/pagination/)